# Запуск скрипта Node.js в Jenkins

Tags: node.js, jenkins, непрерывная-интеграция, devops

Имеется нодовский скрипт, который я могу запустить из корневого каталога проекта (он же WORKSPACE для Jenkins) как

```
node ./scripts/rebuild.js
```

Но как мне его записать его в качестве Powershell-скрипта в build step для Jenkins. Догадываюсь, что исполняемый скрипт нужно указать относительно WORKSPACE, а что делать с нодой.

Файл ноды расположен здесь

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
```

Ее нужно вносить в env или в параметры?

Данный ps-скрипт возращает ошибку

```
&"node $ENV:WORKSPACE\scripts\rebuild.js"
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как исправить?

Comment: можете добавить путь в `ENV`, а можете попробовать [Windows Exe Runner](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Windows+Exe+Runner+Plugin), добавьте переменную и путь, а в job добавьте step с параметрами, что именно надо запустить.

Comment: @approximatenumber да, спасибо. переписал скрипт и в ответе упомянул использование параметров проекта

Answer (score -1):

Итоговый скрипт должен выглядеть следующим образом

```
$NODE = "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe"

&"$NODE" .\scripts\rebuild.js
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Также переменную `NODE` можно добавить в параметры проекта и обращаться к ней как `&"$ENV:NODE" .\scripts\rebuild.js`.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Или в настройки Jenkins, чтобы использовать ее на нескольких проектах.

Использование параметров уменьшает объем скриптов и позволяет менять логику сразу везде, не отслеживая, где использовался данный параметр